# Multiple Aggregate functions with a group by clause

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have the following

```
WorkflowID  FK_UA                DateApprobation
----------- -------------------- -----------------------
1           3                    NULL
2           1                    NULL
3           1                    NULL
4           2                    2013-05-31 09:22:33.000
```

What I'm looking to do is to get a bunch of aggregate fields.

I want to get Approbated workflow , Non-Approbated workflow, All Workflows

The way I'm knowing that is if the "DateApprobation" field is null or has a value.

The thing is, I want to be able to group that by "FK_UA" so I don't know how to have 3 aggregate functions (COUNT) with a group by clause.

I'm looking for a query that can achieve that, I've tried a couple of similar case i found and it returned some weird values.

I tried this :

```
SELECT
    FK_UA
,COUNT(WorkflowID) AS TOTAL
,COUNT(CASE when DateApprobation is not null then 1 else 0 end) AS APPROVED
,COUNT(CASE when DateApprobation is null then 1 else 0 end) AS NOT_APPROVED   
FROM Workflow        
GROUP BY
FK_UA
```

but it always return the same things for all 3 values!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN [DateApprobation] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Approbated count],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [DateApprobation] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Non-Approbated count],
    COUNT(*) as [Total]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY FK_UA
```

If I got you right....

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really had a brain fart and mixed up COUNT and SUM.

Answer (score 1):

#### A standard SQL solution using `COUNT()`

You could have also used `COUNT()` but make sure you turn the values you don't want to count into `NULL`, not `0`, as [aggregate functions do not aggregate `NULL` values in SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/)

```sql
SELECT
  fk_ua,
  COUNT(WorkflowID) AS total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DateApprobation IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS approved,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DateApprobation IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS not_approved
FROM Workflow        
GROUP BY fk_ua
```

In fact, you could take this one step further in your case, because you're already counting the `NOT NULL` values:

```sql
SELECT
  fk_ua,
  COUNT(WorkflowID) AS total,
  COUNT(DateApprobation) AS approved,
  COUNT(WorkflowID) - COUNT(DateApprobation) AS not_approved
FROM Workflow        
GROUP BY fk_ua
```

Or alternatively:

```sql
SELECT fk_ua, total, approved, total - approved AS not_approved
FROM (
  SELECT
    fk_ua,
    COUNT(WorkflowID) AS total,
    COUNT(DateApprobation) AS approved
  FROM Workflow
  GROUP BY fk_ua
) t
```

For large data sets, this *might* be slightly faster as your database should be able to recognise that there are only 2 distinct `COUNT(...)` expressions. Most commercial databases do.

#### A standard SQL solution using `FILTER`

Some SQL dialects, including e.g. PostgreSQL, implement the standard `FILTER` clause, which you can use to make things a bit more readable. Your query would then read:

```sql
SELECT
  fk_ua,
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE DateApprobation IS NOT NULL) AS approved,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE DateApprobation IS NULL) AS not_approved
FROM Workflow        
GROUP BY fk_ua
```